# ASP.NET - Moving a file while a download is in progress

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, download, filesystems

What happens in the scenario:
Consider 3 moments of time, T1 < T2 < T3.
An ASP.NET application is first hit by a request R1 sent at time T1 which starts to download a file and the download will normally be finished at time T3. While the download is still in progress, at T2 another request hits the applications and tries to remove the file which is still downloaded. What will happen? Which request has priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the file is being downloaded , you **wont** be able to move the file

it is in use.

it doesnt related to thread priority.

it's a file system limitations which beats anything.